# Can I right justify div relative to another div

Tags: css

I'd like to right justify the red div relative to blue div. Note the blue div has a percentage for width. Let me know if it would be easier to make this a specific width.

https://jsfiddle.net/5k7uxz0a/

**Edit**
Here's the desired result:

[image]

```
<div id="scr" style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; height: 50px; width: 50px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background: red;"></div>
<div id="container" style="position: relative; background-color: lightblue; height: 300px; width: 20%; overflow: hidden">
    1<br />
    2<br />
    3<br />
    4<br />
    5<br />
    6<br />
    7<br />
    8<br />
    9<br />
    10<br />
    11<br />
    12<br />
    13<br />
    14<br />
    15<br />

</div>
```

**Current Problem**

[image]

Comment: can you move #scr inside #container?

Comment: [Would you mind posting your code and not a picture of it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812), so we don't have to rewrite it when fiddling around?

Comment: Not share a screenshot, is useful but the mandatory is to share the code. I don't tell you anything new, all is specified and writing here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Also you can see @Siguza link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a case for absolute positioning:

```
.blue-div {
    position: relative;
}

.red-div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: What did I do wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/5k7uxz0a/

Comment: Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/x8bkjc81/

Comment: If I understand the question, he needs something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/5k7uxz0a/1/ Otherwise, this answer is the good answer

Comment: According with OP's edition, this is the correct answer.